# ListDensityPlot issue

Tags: plotting

I have the following nasty function:

```
sbbf[ω,κ2,g2]:=(38.4 g1^2 g2^2 Sqrt[κ2^2])/(16 g2^4 (1/10000 + 
   4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 
   8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 
      4 ω^2)) + 
8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 
   4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 
      4 ω^2))) + (9.6 g1^2 (κ2^2 + 
  4 ω^2))/(16 g2^4 (1/10000 + 
   4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 
   8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) (1 + 
      4 ω^2)) + 
8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 
   4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 4 ω^2))) + ((0.5 + 
  nm) (16 g2^4 + 
  8 g2^2 (κ2 - 4 ω^2) + (1 + 
     4 ω^2) (κ2^2 + 4 ω^2)))/(25 (16 g2^4 (1/
     10000 + 4 ω^2) + (κ2^2 + 
     4 ω^2) (16 g1^4 + 
     8 g1^2 (1/100 - 4 ω^2) + (1/10000 + 
        4 ω^2) (1 + 4 ω^2)) + 
  8 g2^2 ((κ2 - 4 ω^2) (1/10000 + 4 ω^2) + 
     4 g1^2 (κ2/100 + 4 ω^2))))
```

And I wish to construct `ListDensityPlot` of the Integral of `sbbf`:

```
popsurf = 
Table[{i, j/5, 
1/(2 π)*
 NIntegrate[
  Evaluate[(sbbf[ω, i, j]) /. {g1 -> 5, 
     nm -> 300}], {ω, -50, 50}]}, {i, 0, 50, 1}, {j, 0, 
250, 1}];
```

When I do, say

```
popsurf[[1]]
```

I get

```
{{0, 0, 3.57973}, {0, 1/5, 14.8892}, {0, 2/5, 44.1781}, {0, 3/5, 
81.5918}, {0, 4/5, 118.734}, {0, 1, 151.284}, {0, 6/5, 178.078}, {0,
7/5, 199.508},...
```

Which is fine, each list tells me the coordinates $(x, y ,z)$ that I will use in my `ListDensityPlot`, which matches the syntax for it. However, when I try to plot it:

```
ListDensityPlot[popsurf]
```

I get a blank density plot. I thought initially I had to `Flatten` `popsurf` but that didn't work as well.

Comment: You probably need `ListDensityPlot3D`

Comment: That works but i'd like a cross-sectional cut view the way ListDensityPlot presents. Is there a way to make it do that from ListDensityPlot3D ?

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. Seems like you just need to flatten only to the first level `Flatten[popsurf, 1]`.

Comment: That works! Thanks!

Comment: @kowalski Probably you can post your solution as an answer to it helps future visitors with the same question.